# Filtering a list according to a parameter in Angular / IONIC 4

Tags: json, angular, ionic4

I have this function that returns a list of pokemons from a JSON URL of pokeapi. 
I need to filter this function so that it shows those of a certain type that I bring with the variable dataPoke. 
The variable is returned with the correct value, but I don't know how to give it filtered output and that it only shows the pokemons of the dataPoke type. 
I get data from https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/3

```
          listadoPokemonFiltrado(salida = 0,dataPoke) {
            console.log("datos recibidos: ", dataPoke);
            return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/pokemon?salida=${salida}`)
              .pipe(
                map(result => { return result['results'];}),
                map(pokemon => {
                  return pokemon.map((arreglo, index) => {
                        arreglo.image = this.obtenerImagen(salida + index + 1);
                        arreglo.pokeIndex = salida + index + 1; 
                        arreglo.type = this.obtenerTypo(dataPoke);
                        arreglo.pokeIndex = arreglo.type;
                        return arreglo;
                  });
                })
              );
          }
          obtenerImagen(index) {
            return `${this.imageUrl}${index}.png`;
          }

          obtenerTypo(index) {
            return `${this.baseUrlTypes}/${index}`;
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading code not in English is certainly a challenge, but I assume that what you're looking for is filtering your array?

```js
listadoPokemonFiltrado(salida = 0, dataPoke) {
    console.log('datos recibidos: ', dataPoke);
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/pokemon?salida=${salida}`).pipe(
        map(result => result['results']),
        map(pokemons => {
            return pokemons
                .filter(pokemon => pokemon.type === dataPoke)
                .map((arreglo, index) => {
                    arreglo.image = this.obtenerImagen(salida + index + 1);
                    arreglo.pokeIndex = salida + index + 1;
                    arreglo.type = this.obtenerTypo(dataPoke);
                    arreglo.pokeIndex = arreglo.type;
                    return arreglo;
                });
        })
    );
}
obtenerImagen(index) {
    return `${this.imageUrl}${index}.png`;
}

obtenerTypo(index) {
    return `${this.baseUrlTypes}/${index}`;
}
```

I have added `.filter(pokemon => pokemon.type === dataPoke)` to filter `results` array.

Comment: Sorry, the names of functions and variables are not in English, it's true. However, the filter in the matrix does not seem to recognize it. Keep returning the list without filtering.

Comment: Can you post the actual http request you're calling? What is `this.baseUrl` in your case?

Comment: As I quote in the post, I call https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon

Comment: OK, so you call this api first and then I assume this has to call another endpoint, let's say `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/` to fetch that specific pokemon with its types in order to filter it, right?